# How can I better fit in with the SO Q&A format?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

I have a lot of trouble forming appropriate questions for the site.

If it is something specific I can almost always find the answer on my own through research - Google, other questions, etc etc.
If it is not that specific it is usually too broad for SO; it is hard to land in the middle.

If I am asking something, I have already researched it and I tend to try and try to predicate my question on those findings.  This bloats the post and makes it more ambiguous what I am asking.  Alternatively, if I don't explicitly exclude answers I know of I'll get them as responses.

To make my questions more useful to others in the future I try to document resources for related information.  This doesn't seem to help, it seems to make the post longer and add camouflage to the question.

The topics I bring up tend to have multiple aspects which makes many respondents struggle to identify what to respond to.

Through my own knowledge or research I sometimes already have an answer but I want to know if there is a better one that a more experienced or knowledgeable person about that would know of.  "hi I have this problem xyz and I came up with a solution but this is probably a *classically known problem with a standard solution*, that I can't find"

I often want to ask what the *best* approach to something is, which gives the question subjectivity which I think goes against the site's values.

My writing style by default is extremely verbose, I work very hard to make it more concise.  Communicating concisely is the most difficult thing that I do.  I have been told that I have a mild form of Autism which seems to fit.

I've tried to explicitly identify the question to be answered in bold text, and I've tried to follow the guidelines for writing questions and read about how to do it well.  I'm not sure I am suited to the Q&A format here but I haven't found a better medium yet.

**How could I better adapt myself to the SO site or is it simply not what I want/need?**

Comment: *Improving* **working** code is not really what Stack Overflow does. That's more the area of CodeReview.SE...but they have different guidelines

Comment: @Paulie_D The exception is if there's a concrete, objective improvement being requested. The only thing is there're almost all vague/subjective things like "how can I make it faster" or "how can I make it more elegant or <this language>-esque"

Comment: Indeed... **specificity** is the key. I suspect that the OP is experienced/wise enought to recognise that if SO is not a good fit for the question there may be an alternative SE site that might be more appropriate. It's just a question of finding it.

Comment: I had a look at few of your questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935929/how-can-i-avoid-memory-errors-and-improve-memory-debugging-capabilities), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56809877/how-can-i-maintain-correlation-between-structure-definitions-and-their-construct), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56688783/how-best-can-a-sentinel-value-be-established-when-the-full-range-of-input-is-pos). Since you're asking about best practices, you should check out [softwareengineering.SE](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "I have a lot of trouble forming appropriate questions for the site." This is an indication of doing it right. Most users don't have that much trouble because they're not spending the effort they need to be. Thank you for trying to write good questions.

Comment: Just to make sure you read what @jpmc26 said: "_Thank you for trying to write good questions._"

Comment: Reminds me of this: "I have only made this letter longer because I have not had the time to make it shorter." - Blaise Pascal

Comment: In general, questions of "how can I make this better", or "what is best out of X or Y", do not fit here. For example, I want to start doing unit tests in JavaScript, and my JavaScript is a bit out of date. So I want to ask "What is a good testing library for JavaScript", and I will ask that question on Reddit.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback, especially the appreciation for working to write good questions.

Answer (score 21):

I don't ask a lot of questions either. I have been here for 6 years, and only have 7 questions. All outside my primary area of expertise. It is the specific, answerable questions that we like here, and ones that won't take more than a blog post worth of effort to answer (those are too broad). If you can already easily find the answers to the questions you have, maybe your best bet is to try you hand at answering questions.

Comment: I agree. By answering questions (for which you know an answer) you will get a good idea of which questions are answerable. SO does not answer opinion-based questions such as "Which database should I use?" or "Is Python better than Java?"

Comment: Yeah, answering questions might provide some helpful insights into asking them.  And I recognize that people have limited time so short and sweet is good though many of the best answers are long and detailed.

Answer (score 12):

I had a look at your six available questions on StackOverflow.

1. "How can I avoid memory errors and improve memory debugging capabilities?"

   This question was closed as too broad. It's an interesting topic but a good answer to this question would result in lengthy texts. StackOverflow is for more specific questions. In the question you said that you wanted to avoid reinventing the wheel, but Q&A of StackOverflow may not be as effective as a textbook for teaching larger subjects. It's main focus is helping you with specific problems.

   Improvement: Find some resource about that topic somewhere else and/or try to perform the task and if you encounter specific problems along the way, ask for them here.
2. "How can I maintain correlation between structure definitions and their construction / destruction code?"

   This question is positively received and got you answers. You don't really need to worry about this question.

   Possible improvement: Shorten the question a bit, by being as succinct as possible without leaving out crucial information. For example a language thing: "When developing and maintaining code, I add a new member to a structure and sometimes forget to add the code to initialize or free it which..." can be shortened to "While adding a new member to a structure I sometimes forget to add the code to initialize or free it which ..."
3. "How best can a Sentinel Value be established when the full range of input is possible?"

   This question is positively received. Please note that "What is the best way to do X.." is already a bad start into a question unless you clearly define what you regard as "quality metric" to optimize.

   You did not write what your personal requirements are and so nobody knows what you value more. Every presented option probably has advantages and disadvantages. If you would say what is important to you, answerers could tell you which option might maximize the value for you. The lack of clear specifications might explain the absence of positively valued answers.
4. "Is there efficiency lost when declaring an automatic variable in a frequently opening block scope { }?"

   It's positively received and has a positive answer. I would say it is a good question.
5. "How to declare a set of structures with non-linear dependency?"

   The question was received positively and got an answer which I think fully answers the question. However, you didn't mark it yet as solution. In the past month you could have commented on the answer and give some feedback why it didn't help you (or mark it as solution if it helped you).

   The separation of context from the core of the question could be better. In a more abstract sense you just want to know how to declare a set of structures with recursive dependencies? I would shift the whole XML discussion either to the beginning or the end with a clear separation of the question.

   Judging by the answer, I guess this could be a duplicate question.
6. "Is CreateCompatibleDC() necessary working with windows on one display?"

   Is a positively received question and has attracted answers. The main question is clear although you tend to ask rather more side questions (I counted 7 question sentences in there.)

   Possible improvement: Boil your question down to the most important 1-3 question sentences and ask them instead. If you are still not sure after getting the answers, ask again with a different aim.

Summary: There is a pattern in all your questions. You try to pack a lot of information and side questions into a single question here. Some of them are quite broad (if one wanted to answer all the questions). Try to break your questions down into even smaller units if that is possible. If you ask "What is the best way to ..." questions, make sure you state what you require/value with regard to the possible solutions. Ask specific questions (questions 3-6 are specific). All your questions are positively received, they are well formulated and understandable. If you try to keep them a more succinct, they may get received even more positively. Use formatting (bullet points, paragraphs) and code examples wisely to make your question as easily understandable as possible.

Comment: Good advice, thank you.  I didn't realize the importance of choosing/accepting answers but I will try to follow up on that.  I will see what I can do to make my questions more targeted and succinct.